# How do you remove all char duplicates in a partial array(unsorted and not supposed to sort)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove the duplicates in this partial array. I tried to compare the ith element with every element but something is going wrong.

```
public class deleteRepeats{
    public static void deleteRepeats(char[] c, int size){
        int i,j;
        char temp;
        char[] newArray = new char[size];
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            newArray[i] = c[i];
        }   
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(newArray[i]==newArray[j]&&i!=j){
                    temp = newArray[j];
                    for(int k=j+1;k<size;k++){
                        newArray[k-1] = newArray[k];
                        newArray[size-1] = temp;
                        size-=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] a = new char[10];
        a[0] = 'a';
        a[1] = 'b';
        a[2] = 'a';
        a[3] = 'e';
        a[4] = 'b';
        a[5] = 'q';
        deleteRepeats(a, 6);

    }
}
```

Current Output: a e e

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by “partial” array? Your code seems to operate on the *whole* array.

Comment: You don't need to pass the size since you can get it from `c.length()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too complicated for a simple problem like this one. To do it faster use two loops like this

```
public static void deleteRepeats2(char[] c, int size){
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char[] newArray = new char[size];

    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (c[j] == c[i]) 
                break;
        }

        if (j == i)
            newArray[k++] = c[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i < k; i++){
        System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to keep your code

```
public static void deleteRepeats(char[] c, int size){
    int i,j;
    char temp;
    char[] newArray = new char[size];
    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        newArray[i] = c[i];
    }   
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if(newArray[i] == newArray[j] && i != j){
                temp = newArray[j];
                for(int k = j; k < size - 1; k++){
                    newArray[k] = newArray[k + 1];
                }
                newArray[size-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  The variable `size` is unnecessary as it is impossible to know the resulting size so it needs to be calculated as you process the source array.  Try your method with `size = 10` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a stream.

```
      char[] c = new char[10];
      c[0] = 'a';
      c[1] = 'b';
      c[2] = 'a';
      c[3] = 'e';
      c[4] = 'b';
      c[5] = 'q';
```

First, your method should return the new array and not change the source.  The main reason is that you can't change the size of the passed array so it will still contain left over 'junk` from the process.  You can always assign the return value of the method to the source array.

Second, you don't need to pass the size of the array. You can get that from `c.length()`

```
      public static char[] deleteRepeats(char[] c) {
         return Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(c).split("")).filter(
            str -> str.charAt(0) != 0).distinct().collect(
                  Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
      }
```

1. Arrays.stream() doesn't accept a `char` array so a String was created and split
2. Then it was filtered to skip the `empty slots` (your array size is larger than its contents)
3. After that using the `distinct()` method eliminated duplicates.
4. Joined the strings together
5. And returned a `char` array

If you prefer a more traditional approach, you can do this.

```java
      public static char[] deleteRepeats(char[] c) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append(c[0]);  // assign first character
          for (char ch : c) {
              if (ch == 0 || sb.indexOf(ch + "") >= 0) {
                 continue;  // skip a 0 value or duplicates
              }   
              sb.append(ch);
           }
           return sb.toString().toCharArray();
      }

      char[] result = deleteRepeats(c);
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
      }
```

Just remember that primitive arrays are initialized to `0` and object arrays are intialized to `null`.  That is why the 0's had to be filtered out in both examples above.